# Greek Text: Letters with accent or breathing mark not appearing?

Tags: languages

Device: Samsung Galaxy S4 
Problem: I am using Anki to help learn Koine Greek, and the characters with a breathing mark or an accent do not appear, this problem also showed up this morning with an online test in Socrative. 
for Example: ἀγγελος will appear as γγελος, and ἡιλίος will appear as ιλ ος

any suggestions on what this problem may be or how to fix it? 
(note: I am not typing greek on my phone only viewing it)

Comment: Are you saying, that when viewing certain text on your phone, it appears different than what it would on a pc?

Comment: yes and no, the problem is with the characters that have accents are not showing up on my phone, when they do on my pc so with the above example: ἡιλίος; is missing the ἡ and the ί, and will appear as  ιλ ος. with a blank space where the character should be. so it shows up fine on my PC, where I enter the characters, however these characters with accents or breathing marks are missing on my phone.